# Persistent mode on USB has different data between computers

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb, persistence

Using LiveLinux USB creator, and [this tutorial](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-larger-than-4gb-casper-partition/), I turned a 32GB flash drive into a live Ubuntu USB with a 26GB casper-rw partition.  This works on the computer that I created the USB with (kept all my data between sessions), but when I boot the USB from other computers it loads different data.  All other computers seem to share one set of data, and the original computer seems to have its own set of data.  I checked the persistant mode boot options, and they're exactly the same.

[This is what the partitions on the USB look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1g9S.png)

My only guess is that its storing all the other computers data in the 4.7 GB partition, and storing the original computer's data in the casper-rw partition, but I have no idea.

Some addition Information.  I tried the USB on 3 other computers that originally booted either Vista, Windows 7, or Windows 8, and use either BIOS or UEFI.  None of them made a difference. Computer 1 (the original) had its own data, and computers 2, 3, and 4 all shared a different set of data.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a casper-rw file in the root of the FAT partition, remove it.

You may also want to shrink the FAT32 partition if the Casper-rw file is large.

However you may want a larger FAT32 partition if you intend using it to transfer data to a Windows machine.

Edit:

It appears that LiveLinux USB creator placed the casper-rw partition on your hard drive.
You can remove it using Gparted. (You might want to copy its contents to the casper-rw partition on the thumb drive.
You can create a new ext2 partition on the thumb drive and label it "casper-rw" using Gparted. Sometimes a Live install does not like it's partition size changed so a fresh install might be better.
This should fix things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm actually working on remaking the USB, the last one got screwed up when the computer shut down incorrectly. If I encounter the same problem that I had the last time, i'll be sure to try what you said.